# Workflow Manager 1.0 will install but NOT configure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow

I have successfully installed Workflow Manager 1.0 (and its prerequisites) on my Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine that is hosting SharePoint 2013.  I attempt to go into the Workflow Manager Configuration.  That comes up and asks me if I want to Create a new farm with Default Settings, a new farm with custom settings, or existing farm.  I've tried both Default settings AND Custom settings.

When the configuration wizard comes up, I attempt to fill out the necessary information.  It seems to connect to the SQL server without a problem.  I only run into an issue when setting the USER ID.  The program totally freezes up and force closes.

I have verified that the USERID is in the correct format and tried multiple different formats.  The problem is that the moment I move the cursor from the USERID field to ANY other field, the program force closes.  I'm not able to hit submit, I'm not able to change any other options.  The moment USERID is manipulated or the cursor LEAVES the USERID field, the program force closes.  It won't even allow me to put in a password before it force closes.

Customer domain is running in Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edittion SP2.
Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

I have copied the errors from event viewer below:

> APPLICATION ERROR
>
> Faulting application name:
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.exe, version: 1.0.20922.0,
>   time stamp: 0x505e1b30 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.17965, time stamp: 0x506dcae6 Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000000bccd Faulting process id: 0x17f8 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cddee198ece72e Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files\Workflow
>   Manager\1.0\Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.exe Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   22ab8b69-4ad5-11e2-af8f-005056965915
>
> .NET Runtime Error
>
> Application: Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.exe Framework
>   Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an
>   unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Stack:    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext,
>   System.Type,
>   System.Nullable`1,
>   System.String, System.DateTime)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext,
>   System.String)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SecurityHelper.IsUserValid(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext,
>   System.String)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.SecurityHelper.IsDomainUserValid(System.String,
>   System.String)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.Common.ValidateUserAttribute.Validate(System.String)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Deployment.ConfigWizard.UICommon.AccountDetailsViewModel.ValidateDomainUser()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Deployment.ConfigWizard.UICommon.AccountDetailsControl.UserIdTextBox_LostFocus(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnLostFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.IsFocused_Changed(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata,
>   System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValueCommon(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata)
>   at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.ClearValue(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyKey)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.OnFocusedElementChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex,
>   System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata,
>   System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,
>   System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean,
>   System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,
>   System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotKeyboardFocus(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
>   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()    at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(System.Windows.IInputElement)
>   at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()    at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.Navigate(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.Input.TraversalRequest,
>   System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys, System.Windows.DependencyObject)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.Navigate(System.Windows.DependencyObject,
>   System.Windows.Input.Key, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventHandler,
>   System.Windows.Input.ProcessInputEventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()    at
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr,
>   System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32,
>   System.Windows.Input.RawKeyboardActions, Int32, Boolean, Boolean,
>   Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.TranslateAndDispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG
>   ByRef)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Deployment.ConfigWizard.App.Main()

****More Information :****
I have installed also cumulative update to avoid crash but still I am getting force to close workflow wizard. I have used users which are already added in administrator groups.

We are using 3 tier architecture for Sharepoint 2013.

Also we have made Alias of Domain controller. Eg:-Alias is "labs" for domain "xyz.ab.com".

And we are using labs\spadmin and labs\spservice for Workflow Manager Configuration 1.0

Is there any issue with Domain Alias "labs" as Workflow gives error  "Specified RunAs account is invalid" or "Force close the application".

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the PowerShell commands and configuring the farm command by command?

Comment: I have added more information..Please check again.

Comment: You have setup a DNS alias which has no impact on the domain name you can use to log in with.  See Spence Harbar's article on configuring Workflow Manager [Link](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

PLs check whether the account is a domain admin and check they system is joined in domain properly. If not try to re join in the domain again and then try to configure workflow. It will work fine.